# Why log4j-slf4j-impl is not lock free?

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j, project-reactor, lock-free

I use [Async](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html) log4j2 over slf4j in our app and i was sure that is non-blocking. But after integrating [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) i got a surprise:

```
java.lang.Exception: [worker-1-8] Blocking call: sun.misc.Unsafe#park
 at reactor.blockhound.BlockHound$Builder.lambda$install$6(BlockHound.java:318)
 at reactor.blockhound.BlockHoundRuntime.checkBlocking(BlockHoundRuntime.java:46)
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
 at com.lmax.disruptor.TimeoutBlockingWaitStrategy.signalAllWhenBlocking(TimeoutBlockingWaitStrategy.java:62)
 at com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.publish(MultiProducerSequencer.java:218)
 at com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.translateAndPublish(RingBuffer.java:990)
 at com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.tryPublishEvent(RingBuffer.java:538)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor.tryEnqueue(AsyncLoggerConfigDisruptor.java:392)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig.logToAsyncDelegate(AsyncLoggerConfig.java:135)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig.log(AsyncLoggerConfig.java:116)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:460)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:162)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2190)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2144)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2127)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2020)
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1891)
 at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.info(Log4jLogger.java:184)
```

Is this expected behavior or am i missing something?

Comment: There are plenty of places even in that very documentation that indicate it's not non-blocking. Perhaps there's confusion between asynchronous, non-blocking and lock-free?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2's async logging just hands off the I/O part to a separate thread via the disruptor (a kind of ring buffer). The producer signals the consumer using Java's built-in `notify()`, which has to acquire a lock.